# issue to set text inside input field

Tags: jquery, html

I have search program where I have to find some text after click on that search result it should set into input box but **it gives me some space before text**

You can check it on below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/VcXtC/

```
$("tbody > tr").click(function(){
    var proid = $(this).text().split(":"); $("#searchInput").val(proid[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$("tbody > tr")` to `$("tbody td")` to select the table cell instead of the row.

Answer (score 4):

**Working demo** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

API:

`.trim`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

**code**

```
$("tbody > tr").click(function(){
    var proid = $(this).text().split(":");
    alert(proid[0]);
    $("#searchInput").val(proid[0].trim());
});
```

Comment: @user2826111 Indeed `:)` and `.trim` will resolve your main issue: "it gives me some space before text". Glad you are able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

use **jquery trim** for this Reference [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Replace :

```
$("#searchInput").val(proid[0]);
```

To:

```
$("#searchInput").val(proid[0].trim());
```

You should trigger click event like

```
$("tbody > tr > td").click(function(){
    var proid = $(this).text().split(":"); $("#searchInput").val(proid[0].trim());
});
```

[JSFIDDEL DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VcXtC/4/)

Comment: Why jQuery...?! JS has a native method to do this... `$("#searchInput").val(proid[0].trim());`

Comment: @DJDavid98 IE8 and below don't support the `.trim()` method.

Comment: The latest jQuery doesn't support IE8 and below either AFAIK.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Yes, jQuery 2+ doesn't support those browsers (_fortunately_).

Comment: @undefined is right, but using jQuery for everything isn't always the best way to go.

Comment: @undefined ya that answer also correct i know but it was some complicated than this as far as first look.

Comment: thanks, Ya just by simply using .trim() it works but better to target row I just target cell it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of all the spaces between `<tr>` and `<td>`. Either put the click handler on the `tbody > tr > td`, or use `proid[0].trim()` to remove the spaces.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/VcXtC/1/)